# print_r($_FILES) Undefined array key

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to use print_r to show the data that is inserting from the form to see if the data are really sending after the submit but the outpute for the files is

> "Warning: Undefined array key "actenaisss" in C:\xampp\htdocs\BEA1\insertion1.php on line 21"

here is my code:

```
<?php
require ("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['suiv'])){

    $typeban = $_POST['typeban'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $nais = $_POST['nais'];
    $lnais = $_POST['lnais'];
    $pprenom = $_POST['pprenom'];
    $mnom = $_POST['mnom'];
    $mprenom = $_POST['mprenom'];
    $actenais = $_POST['actenais'];
    $typepie = $_POST['typepie'];
    $numpi = $_POST['numpi'];
    $datedeliv = $_POST['datedeliv'];
    $delivpar = $_POST['delivpar'];
    $prof = $_POST['prof'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $actenaisss = $_FILES['actenaisss'];
    $piec = $_FILES['piec'];
    $resid = $_FILES['resid'];

       
       print_r($typeban);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($nom);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($prenom);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($nais);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($lnais);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($pprenom);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($mnom);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($mprenom);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($actenais);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($typepie);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($numpi);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($datedeliv);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($delivpar);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($prof);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($numero);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($email);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($actenaisss);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($piec);
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($resid);
}
?>
```

Here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulaire compte depot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insertion1.php" >
       <table>
             <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name="prsnphysique" value="Je suis une personne physique." required="true">Je suis une personne physique </td>
             <td> <label>Type de compte bancaire</label>
                     <select name="typeban">
                            <option>Compte depot</option>
                            <option>Compte CEDAC</option>
                            <option>Compte personnel BEA</option>
                     </select></td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Nom</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom</label>
            <input type="text" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" required="true">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Date de naissance</label>
            <input type="date" name="nais" placeholder="Date de naissance" required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Lieu de naissance</label>
            <input type="text" name="lnais" placeholder="Lieu de naissance" required="true">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom du pere</label>
            <input type="text" name="pprenom" required="true" placeholder="Prenom du père">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Nom de la mere</label>
            <input type="text" name="mnom" required="true" placeholder="Nom de la mère">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom de la mere</label>
            <input type="text" name="mprenom" required="true" placeholder="Prenom de la mère">
        </td>
        <td>    
                     <label>Numero de l'acte de naissance</label>
                   <input type="number" name="actenais" required="true" placeholder="Numero de l'acte de naissance">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Piece d'identite presente</label>
            <select name="typepie">
                <option>Carte d'identite</option>
                <option>Permis de conduire</option>
                <option>Passeport</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Numero de la piece d'identite</label>
            <input type="number" name="numpi" required="true" placeholder="Numero de la piece d'identite">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Delivree le</label>
            <input type="date" name="datedeliv" required="true" placeholder="Delivree le">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>delivree par</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivpar" required="true" placeholder="Delivree par">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Profession</label>
            <input type="text" name="prof" required="true" placeholder="Profession">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Numero de telephone</label>
            <input type="number" name="numero" required="true" placeholder="Numero de telephone">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" placeholder="E-mail">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
              <td>
                     <label>Pieces justificatifs</label><br><br>
                     Acte de naissance  <input type="file" name="actenaisss" required="true"><br><br>
                     Piece d'identite  <input type="file" name="piec" required="true"><br><br>
                     Certificat de residence/ Facture d'electricite<br>Hebergement/ Contrat location  <input type="file" name="resid" required="true">
              </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
       <input type="submit" name="suiv" value="Suivant">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this, Thank you

Comment: Please post your `<form>`. Does it have the proper `enctype` attribute?

Comment: Yes it has the enctype attribute but still is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it all prints well. I guess you did not upload all files in the corresponding file input. You should check for all the variables first with isset and return false if any required values are required.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't get you but I did the isset for the files and the return false and that what happened that retured to me the false

Comment: This means you did not select a file in the form! Put required on every input.

Comment: The require is already in every input

Comment: However i cannot reproduce your error... Are you sure your max_upload_file php ini is enough as well as max_upload_files?

Comment: I just refreshed the page and it worked Thank you